# Как воспроизвести несколько анимаций подряд и зациклить их?

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation

Использую animate.css. Нужно зациклить такую анимацию:
При помощи fadeInRight слева появляется элемент, ждем 5 сек и при помощи fadeOut скрываем его. Но после этого элемент появляется и анимация останавливается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать что-бы после того как элемент скрылся при помощи fadeOut, анимация началась сначала?

```
animation: fadeInRight 1s, fadeOut 2s;
animation-delay: 0s, 5s;
```

Comment: вообще как бы давно уже выдумали библиотеки специально для анимаций типа anime.js greensock и тому подобные ...

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  animation: blink 5s linear infinite both;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
   10% { opacity: 0; }
   30% { opacity: 1; }
   70% { opacity: 1; }
   90% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Без js - никак. Можно использовать одну анимацию для всего этого действа.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  animation: xxx 8s infinite;
}

@keyframes xxx {
  from {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 300px / 2));
  }
  
  12.5%, 75% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100vw - 300px / 2));
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/23964611ba1cc30ca3e3e67907515937.jpg">
```